# I want to check and run the below code but it is giving me error identifier expected

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me why the program is failing to execute in the third part i.e. when i m passing copy constructor?
It says that the identifier expected near Stud(studs)

```
class Stud
{
String name;
int rollno;
double per;

Stud()
 {
  name="";
  rollno=0;
  per=0.0;
 }

Stud(String n,int rn,double p)
 {
  name=n;
  rollno=rn;
  per=p;
 }

Stud(Studs)
 {
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
 }


void display()
{
 System.out.println(name+ "\t" +rollno+ "\t" +per);
}
}

class StudApp14
 {
  public static void main(String a[])
   {
    Stud s1=new Stud();
    Stud s2=new Stud("Amit",501,65.0);
    Stud s3=new Stud(s2);
    s1.display();
    s2.display();
    s3.display();
   }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a space between Stud and s in your actual code? It just looks like Studs here.

Comment: Please put some effort into fixing your problem before asking a question. We're not going to sit here and fix every tiny problem that could be fixed with a minute of debugging.

Comment: You should use an IDE or something that will provide you with a more elaborate error-checker. If you were to be using, say, Netbeans and made this code, you'd know about the error before you even compiled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stud(Studs)
 {
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
 }
What is  "Studs"? there is no definition for it.

Maybe you meant

```
Stud (Stud s ) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is this constructor

```
Stud(Studs)
 {
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
 }
```

It should be (You are missing space between type and variable name):

```
Stud(Stud s)
 {
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
 }
```

Comment: but what i the issue that I m asking?

Comment: @Akshay: Issue is you are missing type, see other constrcutors, where String is type and n is name of the variable.

Comment: @Doorknob: Initially my answer has Stud studs instead of Stud s, which is wrong because inside constructor s is the one being used. Someone downvoted but didn't have commonsense to highlight mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this constructor:

```
Stud(Studs)
{
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
}
```

You meant this:

```
Stud(Stud s)
{
  name=s.name;
  rollno=s.rollno;
  per=s.per;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler thinks that "Studs" is a type and is missing an identifier.  So if you follow the compiler error strictly and decide to fix it by adding an identifier like so:

```
Stud(Studs s)
```

Then you will get an error saying:

```
error: cannot find symbol
```

Which means that the compiler searched for the type "Studs" and couldn't find it.

More about java types, values, and variables here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html